# Tamaño archivo log en Raspbian

Tags: python

estoy implementando archivos log en cada código que se encuentra corriendo en la Raspberry (30 archivos). El sistema lo tengo con log rotativo diario. Pero he tenido problemas. 
Estoy cambiando a log por tamaño, alguna sugerencia para fijar el tamaño de este?

Correo en una microSD de 16GB.

Gracias.

Comment: ¿Usas [logging](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html)? En ese caso  el parámetro `maxBytes` de `RotatingFileHandler` debería ser lo que buscas, a no ser que esté malentendiendo algo.

Comment: Exacto, estoy utilizando maxBytes. Pero tengo dudas con el tamaño que debería asignarle, estaba pensando en 5 MB. ¿Qué opinas?

Comment: Ufff eso es muy relativo y es normal que te surjan dudas. No hay una regla. Hay que tener en cuanta muchos factores, entre ellos el espacio disponible lógicamente, pero no el único. Va a depender en gran medida del número de entradas que esperas que se generen en un tiempo x, del tamaño de cada entrada y no menos importante que ventana de tiempo quieres tener más u menos cubierta por el log. No es lo mismo una app que te genere 300 entradas de log al día que una que genere 5. Yo me suelo mover entre 5-20 MB pero es algo muy relativo y que hay que valorar para cada caso concreto.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda.